# How do I concisely co_await on a (non-co-routine) function that is being executed?

Tags: asio

I'm currently able to do something like:

```
co_await async_spawn(some_executor, []() { /* DO SOMETHING SLOW */ })
```

with:

```
template <typename Executor, typename Func>
auto async_spawn(Executor& executor, Func&& func) {
  return asio::co_spawn(
      executor,
      [func = std::forward<Func>(func)](
          auto&&... args) -> asio::awaitable<std::invoke_result_t<Func, decltype(args)...>> {
        co_return func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
      },
      asio::use_awaitable);
}
```

but the entire `async_spawn` function, and actually making a co-routine for what I'm spawning - seem unnecessary? Is there a more concise way?